# Why are size of words in two tables not same?

Tags: tables, ieeetran

Why does the words in the top table are bigger than ones in the bottom table? 
 How can I make it the same size with the bottom ones (make it smaller)?
[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\rule{30pt}{40pt}

  \caption{A figure}

  \vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
  \captionof{table}{A table}

          \begin{tabular}{c*{4}{p{0.125\linewidth}}}
           \toprule
          &\multicolumn{3}{c}{NUMBER} \\
             \cmidrule(lrr){2-4}
            NO  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}                 \\\midrule
            H & K\textsubscript{NI} & K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG   \\\midrule
            K &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI} & NDG   \\\midrule
            C & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI} &  K\textsubscript{NOT}      \\\midrule
            D & NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            L &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            M & K\textsubscript{NI}  &  NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT}        \\\bottomrule
          \end{tabular}

  \vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
  \begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{ANOTHER TABLE}
  \label{tab:table7}
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
                            \toprule
    A & B& C\\ \midrule
    1000 &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG         \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For reasons best known to the designers of the `IEEEtran` document class, the contents of `table` environments are automatically rendered at `\footnotesize` -- for a 20% linear reduction in font size -- whereas the contents of `figure` environments are not subjected to this treatment.

To wit, the first table in the following screenshot is embedded in a `figure` environment, while the second is embedded in a `table` environment. Do note that the contents of the two `tabular` environments are *identical*.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}

\begin{document}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of column
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\captionof{table}{A table in a figure environment}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{NUMBER} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
NO  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}            \\ \midrule
H & K\textsubscript{NI} & K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG  \\ \midrule
K &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI} & NDG \\ \midrule
M & K\textsubscript{NI}  &  NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

% same 'tabular' environment, but not embedded in a 'table' env.
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{A table in a table environment}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{NUMBER} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
NO  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}            \\ \midrule
H & K\textsubscript{NI} & K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG  \\ \midrule
K &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI} & NDG \\ \midrule
M & K\textsubscript{NI}  &  NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of column
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never know that. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @hana - If you're employing the `IEEEtran` document class because somebody (a journal's editorial staff, maybe?) has told you to do so, I would definitely *not* mess with the document class's settings, lest your paper get rejected for something as trivial as "violating the journal's input requirements". If that's not the case, i.e., if you're free to mess about as you see fit, you could achieve your desired "fix" by issuing the instruction `\normalsize` right after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: I just started with LaTeX probably one week ago so I don't know much. I just wanted to add the figure and table side by side so I got many helps to get that done above. Is there any way to fix this without  "violating the journal's input requirements"?

Comment: @hana - The "fix", then, would consist of embedding the `minipage` environments that contain the graphic and the associated `tabular` environment in a `table` environment, not a `figure` environment...

Comment: thanks, that works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - I can only assume that in the OP's real document, both the graphic and the `tabular` material manage to both fit inside the width of a column. This assumption could be incorrect, of course.

Comment: @Mico - So it does.  Never mind.  OTOH, I don't think IEEE will like the idea of putting a table and figure side-by-side in one column.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Mico: 
 I used this `{c*{4}{p{0.125\linewidth}}}` so it fits the column. However, the table still looks too big compared to my image. Is there any way to make the table smaller without violating the journal's input requirements? Also how can I do middle alignment of the figure and the table?

Comment: You are already using \footnotesize.  The next smaller size is \scriptsize (as in subscripts).  You can use [c] instead of [b] with minipages to align middles.

Comment: @hana - Since the table in question has just four columns, I don't understand why you would specify `{c*{4}{p{0.125\linewidth}}}`, implying that 5 columns needed to be defined.

Comment: @Mico to be honest I don't know exactly what it does. I understand it as dividing the table into 4 columns with centre align and each columns has width of `0.125\linewidth`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea of what might be acceptable to IEEE.  First, I made the image as large as possible (minus a `\tabcolsep` gap).  I placed the table caption alone above the tabular.  I placed the figure and tabular side-by-side.Then I placed the figure caption alone below the image.

I show how to handle the case when the image is width limited or height limited.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[ht]
% first measure the width of the tabular
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}[b]{cccc}
           \toprule
          &\multicolumn{3}{c}{NUMBER} \\
             \cmidrule(lrr){2-4}
            NO  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}                 \\\midrule
            H & K\textsubscript{NI} & K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG   \\\midrule
            K &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI} & NDG   \\\midrule
            C & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI} &  K\textsubscript{NOT}      \\\midrule
            D & NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            L &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            M & K\textsubscript{NI}  &  NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT}        \\\bottomrule
          \end{tabular}}%
% place image and table with caption side-by-side
\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd0-\tabcolsep}]{example-image}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\wd0}
  \caption{A table}
  \usebox0
\end{minipage}\par
% place figure caption alone on the bottom
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd0-\tabcolsep}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
% first measure the height of the tabular
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
           \toprule
          &\multicolumn{3}{c}{NUMBER} \\
             \cmidrule(lrr){2-4}
            NO  & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}                 \\\midrule
            H & K\textsubscript{NI} & K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG   \\\midrule
            K &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI} & NDG   \\\midrule
            C & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI} &  K\textsubscript{NOT}      \\\midrule
            D & NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            L &  K\textsubscript{NOT} & NDG & K\textsubscript{NI}       \\\midrule
            M & K\textsubscript{NI}  &  NDG &  K\textsubscript{NOT}        \\\bottomrule
          \end{tabular}}%
% place table caption alone on top
\null\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
  \caption{A table}
  \hrule height0pt% to keep \belowcaptionskip from being eaten
\end{minipage}\par
% place image (with caption) and tabular side-by-side
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0}]{example-image-10x16}}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \usebox0
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice too. I tried something similar but couldn't do aligment. I tried you code but got these errors `Undefined control sequence.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Comment: I've been tweaking the code all along, so have no idea which version gave the error.

Comment: This version works but how can I insert my pdf image? I replaced `example-image` with `myimage.pdf` in `\includegraphics[width={\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd0-\tabcolsep}]{example-image}\hfill` but I got error.

Comment: Assuming myimage.pdf is in the same directory, that shouldn't happen.  BTW, you can probably drop the pdf extension.

Comment: Oh, I used overleaf and it worked now. I just realized that I use the suggestion from overleaf for to insert image that causes error.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use this for my article.

Comment: How can I reduce the table size without changing the font size?

Comment: I want to leave more space between the figure and table in the first case with width limited. How can I do that here?

Comment: I used \tabcolsep for the gap (used in the [width=...] calculation.  Simply replace it with a larger distance.  \columnsep would be my second choice.

Comment: How would you reduce the width of the first column? It's too big and if I increases tabcolsep it makes figure go to bottom instead.

Comment: Don't **change** `\tabcolsep`; it is used by tabular.  Replace it, as in `[width={\dimexpr \columnwidth-\wd0-20pt}]`.